# How to prevent my JPanel from packing itself (Swing)

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have a `JPanel` which works allright. But there's a problem. I add a component which draws background for whole `JFrame` and also adds some buttons.

Problem starts when the `JPanel` "packs"(`pack()`) itself and only half of the background is visible.

I've tried to set panel's size and preferred size but it didn't work.

Comment: Post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Use a BorderLayout on the JFrame and add the JPanel to the CENTER area of the layout. Add whatever you want to the JPanel.

Comment: can you please post the code?

Comment: [Don't use `setPreferredSize()` when you really mean to override `getPreferredSize()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513).

Comment: I've already changed the code so i can't post original one. But my changes still didn't fix it.

P.S. My JFrame uses cardLayout.

Comment: I think it may have something to do with the `CardLayout`. The layout will size itself according the _largest_ component in the layout. So if there's a layout that is bigger than the preferred size of the background panel, it will stretch the background panel. If the image is hard coded with size values that are less than the stretched size, that's one thing that could cause it. Maybe use `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` for the `width` and `height` of `drawImage` and see what happens. This is all just a guess without seeing your code. Or a runnable example.